# Loop java back to the beginning of the code

Tags: java

I am looking for a way to loop a program back to the beginning if the user chooses at the end.

The program is a menu program I have used switch statements all throughout at the end after it prints out the receipt and all other details required have been validated it is meant to ask the user if they want to order again and should loop forever until they choose to exit.

I have tried another switch statement

```
    switch (end) {
case 1:
coffee = keyboard.nextInt();
break;
case 2:
tea = keyboard.nextInt();
break;
case 3:
System.out.println("Bye bye\n");
System.exit(0);
break;}
```

But obviously it will take the next in but will not go back to that part of the program how would you make it do this ?

Thanks

Comment: You can enclose the above code in a while(true){} block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go for

```
while(true){
   switch(end)
…..
…..
…..
…..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the whole relevant section inside a loop; for this sort of "do you want to continue" situation, usually a `do...while` loop.